# Remove Video controls in Mozilla

Tags: javascript, html, css, firefox, html5-video

How to disable or remove certain controls like play/pause button, timeline in mozilla firefoz browser with CSS.

The code used for other browsers is:

```
video::-webkit-media-controls-play-button,
video::-webkit-media-controls-pause-button {
  display: none;
}

/* Hide the timebar */
video::-webkit-media-controls-timeline {
  display: none;
}

video::-webkit-media-controls-current-time-display,
video::-webkit-media-controls-time-remaining-display,
video::-webkit-media-controls-elapsed-time-display {
  display: none !important;
}

/* video::-webkit-media-controls-fullscreen-button {
    display: none;
} */

video::-webkit-media-controls-volume-slider,
video::-webkit-media-controls-mute-button {
  display: none;
}
video::-webkit-media-controls-start-playback-button {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: seems mozilla doesn't consider this non-standard CSS to be important enough to implement - i.e. you can't

Comment: I believe it's not standard, and thus once again only webkit proposes this extension